# No Hibernate Session bound to thread exception when linking it to REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to link my ContactService to my ContactDao so that it can be retrieved from the database and then consumed by a REST Client but I receive the following error when running the REST Client:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:685)
    at com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.service.ContactDaoImpl.findAll(ContactDaoImpl.java:40)
    at com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.service.ContactServiceMockImplementation.findAll(ContactServiceMockImplementation.java:56)
    at com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.restful.controller.ContactController.listData(ContactController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:685)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:851)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Here is my RestClientMain:

```
package com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.restful;

import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.domain.Contact;
import com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.domain.Contacts;
import com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.service.ContactDao;


public class RestfulClientMain {

    private static final String URL_GET_ALL_CONTACTS = "http://localhost:8080/Contact/contacts";
    private static final String URL_GET_CONTACT_BY_ID = "http://localhost:8080/Contact/contacts/{id}";
    private static final String URL_CREATE_CONTACT = "http://localhost:8080/Contact/contacts/";
    private static final String URL_UPDATE_CONTACT = "http://localhost:8080/Contact/contacts/{id}";
    private static final String URL_DELETE_CONTACT = "http://localhost:8080/Contact/contacts/{id}"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("classpath:restful-client-app-context.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        Contacts contacts;
        Contact contact;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = ctx.getBean("restTemplate", RestTemplate.class);

        // Test retrieve all contacts
        System.out.println("Testing retrieve all contacts:");
        contacts = restTemplate.getForObject(URL_GET_ALL_CONTACTS, Contacts.class);
        listContacts(contacts); 

        // Test retrieve contact by id
        System.out.println("Testing retrieve a contact by id :");
        contact = restTemplate.getForObject(URL_GET_CONTACT_BY_ID, Contact.class, 1);
        System.out.println(contact);
        System.out.println("");

        // Test update contact
        contact = restTemplate.getForObject(URL_UPDATE_CONTACT, Contact.class, 1);
        contact.setFirstName("Kim Fung");
        System.out.println("Testing update contact by id :");
        restTemplate.put(URL_UPDATE_CONTACT, contact, 1);
        System.out.println("Contact update successfully: " + contact);
        System.out.println(""); 

        // Testing delete contact
        restTemplate.delete(URL_DELETE_CONTACT, 1);
        System.out.println("Testing delete contact by id :");
        contacts = restTemplate.getForObject(URL_GET_ALL_CONTACTS, Contacts.class);
        listContacts(contacts);

        // Testing create contact
        System.out.println("Testing create contact :");
        Contact contactNew = new Contact();
        contactNew.setFirstName("JJ");
        contactNew.setLastName("Gosling");
        contactNew.setBirthDate(new Date());
        contactNew = restTemplate.postForObject(URL_CREATE_CONTACT, contactNew, Contact.class);
        System.out.println("Contact created successfully: " + contactNew);       

    }

    private static void listContacts(Contacts contacts) {
        for (Contact contact: contacts.getContacts()) {
            System.out.println(contact);
        }   
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

ContactController:

```
package com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.restful.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

import com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.domain.Contact;
import com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.domain.Contacts;
import com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.service.ContactService;


@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/contacts")
public class ContactController {

    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactController.class);


    @Autowired
    private ContactService contactService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Contacts listData(WebRequest webRequest) {
        return new Contacts(contactService.findAll());
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Contact findContactById(@PathVariable Long id) {     
        return contactService.findById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Contact create(@RequestBody Contact contact, HttpServletResponse response) {
        logger.info("Creating contact: " + contact);
        contactService.save(contact);
        logger.info("Contact created successfully with info: " + contact);
        response.setHeader("Location",  "/contacts/" + contact.getId());
        return contact;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseBody
    public void update(@RequestBody Contact contact, @PathVariable Long id) {
        logger.info("Updating contact: " + contact);
        contactService.save(contact);
        logger.info("Contact updated successfully with info: " + contact);
        //return contact;
    }   

    @RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseBody
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        logger.info("Deleting contact with id: " + id);
        Contact contact = contactService.findById(id);
        contactService.delete(contact);
        logger.info("Contact deleted successfully");
    }   

}
```

ContactDaoImpl:

```
package com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.service;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.domain.Contact;


@Component
@Repository("contactDao")
@Transactional
public class ContactDaoImpl implements ContactDao {

    private Logger _logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContactDaoImpl.class);

    private SessionFactory _sessionFactory; 

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return _sessionFactory;
    }

    @Resource
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this._sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
        _logger.debug("SessionFactory class: " + sessionFactory.getClass().getName());
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Contact> findAll() {
        List<Contact> result = _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Contact c").list();
        return result;
    }

    public List<Contact> findAllWithDetail() {
        return _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("Contact.findAllWithDetail").list();
    }

    public Contact findById(Long id) {
        return (Contact) _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
                getNamedQuery("Contact.findById").setParameter("id", id).uniqueResult();
    }

    public Contact save(Contact contact) {
        _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(contact);
        _logger.info("Contact saved with id: " + contact.getId());
        return contact;
    }

    public void delete(Contact contact) {
        _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(contact);
        _logger.info("Contact deleted with id: " + contact.getId());
    }

}
```

ContactServiceImpl (ignore comments as they were used for mock testing purposes):

```
package com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.domain.Contact;
import com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.domain.Contacts;

@Component
@Service("contactService")
public class ContactServiceMockImplementation implements ContactService {

    //private Contacts _contacts;
    @Autowired
    private ContactDao contactDao;

//  public ContactServiceMockImplementation() {
//      Contact contact1 = new Contact();
//      contact1.setId(1L);
//      contact1.setVersion(1);
//      contact1.setFirstName("Clint");
//      contact1.setLastName("Eastwood");
//      contact1.setBirthDate(new Date());
//      
//      Contact contact2 = new Contact();
//      contact2.setId(1L);
//      contact2.setVersion(1);
//      contact2.setFirstName("Robert");
//      contact2.setLastName("Redford");
//      contact2.setBirthDate(new Date());
//      
//      Contact contact3 = new Contact();
//      contact3.setId(1L);
//      contact3.setVersion(1);
//      contact3.setFirstName("Michael");
//      contact3.setLastName("Caine");
//      contact3.setBirthDate(new Date());
//      
//      List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
//      contactList.add(contact1);
//      contactList.add(contact2);
//      contactList.add(contact3);
//      
//      _contacts = new Contacts(contactList);
//  }

    @Override
    public List<Contact> findAll() {
        //return _contacts.getContacts();
        return contactDao.findAll();
    }

//  @Override
//  public List<Contact> findByFirstName(String firstName) {
//      List<Contact> results = new ArrayList<Contact>();
//      
//      for(Contact contact : _contacts.getContacts()) {
//          if(contact.getFirstName().equals(firstName)) {
//              results.add(contact);
//          }
//      }
//      return results;
//  }

    @Override
    public Contact findById(Long id) {
//      Contact result = null;
//      
//      for(Contact contact : _contacts.getContacts()) {
//          if(contact.getId() == id) {
//              result = contact;
//              break;
//          }
//      }
//      return result;
        return contactDao.findById(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Contact save(Contact contact) {
        //return contact;
        return contactDao.save(contact);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Contact contact) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        contactDao.delete(contact);
    }

}
```

Here is my restful-client-app-context.xml which includes the Hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2">
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:schema.sql"/>
        <jdbc:script location="classpath:test-data.sql"/>
    </jdbc:embedded-database>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="springSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>  

    <!-- <bean id="contactDao" class="com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.service.ContactDao"></bean> -->

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.service" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="springSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.aucklanduni.spring.webservices.domain"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>        
    </bean>
    <bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <!--  <constructor-arg ref="httpRequestFactory"/>-->
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                    <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller"/>
                    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller"/>
                    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                        <list>
                            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                                <constructor-arg index="0" value="application"/>
                                <constructor-arg index="1" value="xml"/>
                            </bean>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>                
            </list>
        </property>    
    </bean>

    <bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller">
        <property name="mappingLocation" value="classpath:oxm-mapping.xml"/>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Comment: Show us your hibernate configuration and Repository Configuration. Does the repo config has a TransacrionManager defined?

Comment: have added it for your reference

Comment: Can you try adding <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop> in your hibernate propertes?

Comment: I made that change but now when I run the restful client, I get this error- Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: is there something wrong with my Service and Dao Implementations?